# Excel Sorting not working due to Range object

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

This macro is based off one I recorded, but have tweaked to cope with possible absence of 3 of the 4 sorting criteria. I can't figure out why my Macro works when the range criteria is specific, but not when I'm referencing a single cell and extrapolating.

With this line the sorting works
        `.SetRange Range("A1:W162")`

With this line it doesn't sort.
        `.SetRange Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)`
I've stepped through and can confirm it's selecting the correct range

I don't want use the line with specific cells because future exports will be different sized.

This is the full subroutine (the relevant bit is near the bottom).

Thanks!

```
Sub SortByScoreAndCost()

Dim Score As Range
Dim Cost As Range
Dim YN As Range
Dim OriginalScore As Range

Set Score = Cells.Find("Score")
Set Cost = Cells.Find("Cost")
Set YN = Cells.Find("Y/N")
Set OriginalScore = Cells.Find("Original Score")

Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select

ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear

ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    Score.Offset(1, 0), Score.End(xlDown)), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal

        If Cells.Find("Cost") Is Nothing _
            Then
            Else: ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range _
                (Cost.Offset(1, 0), Cost.End(xlDown)), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption _
                :=xlSortNormal
        End If

        If Cells.Find("Y/N") Is Nothing _
            Then
            Else: ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range _
                (YN.Offset(1, 0), YN.End(xlDown)), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption _
                :=xlSortNormal
        End If

        If Cells.Find("Original Score") Is Nothing _
            Then
            Else: ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range _
                (OriginalScore.Offset(1, 0), Original.End(xlDown)), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption _
                :=xlSortNormal
        End If

With ActiveSheet.Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:W162") 'works with this line
    .SetRange Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight) 'doesn't work if replaced with this line
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: As general advice, which is why I've not included this in my answer, I would try and avoid using `active`, so instead of `ActiveSheet` I would suggest using `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Whatever the name of the sheet is")` This may be longer and could require the use of `With` but in this way, it is very unlikely that Excel tries to reference the wrong sheet and throw an error.

Comment: Hi @SilentRevolution, thanks for the advice. However, this is part of a whole series of subroutines that are called by a master subroutine. They are located in my personal.xlb, because I plan on using them across a variety of workbooks that may be opened at times when I don't already have excel open. These are exports/downloads from a Salesforce web database. So it'll be ran on different sheets, that'll have varied names. This is why I've set it up with ActiveSheet, rather than a named workbook

Answer (score 0):

`Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)` refers to a single cell range, not similar to `A1:W162`. Assuming `A1:W162` is the range where all the data on your sheet is. The line refers to `W162` only. The `Range.End` property is explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-end-property-excel) and it shows that it does not retain the starting point.

Try `Range("A1:"& Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight).Address)` instead as this should create a range similar to `A1:W162`. The first part is the string `"A1:"` and `Range("A1).End(xlDown).end(xlToRight).Address` returns the string `"$W$162"` Together they form `"A1:$W$162"`

With the comment I made on your question in mind I would suggest the code below.

```
Dim wsData as Worksheet 'Add worksheet variable

Set wsData = ThisworkBook.Worksheets("Name of your data sheet")

With wsData.Sort 'Instead of using ActiveSheet
    .SetRange wsData.Range(wsData.Cells(1, 1), wsData.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
```

Comment: Thanks again @SilentRevolution. I'm afraid your suggested solution didn't work for some reason (that I couldn't establish). However, your advice did make me realise what I was doing wrong and I've managed to correct it now with the following section of code:

`    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With`

Comment: No problem at all @JamesH, It's very hard to tell without why it won't work without the actual document. I'm glad though that my suggestion helped you out.